# SQL Server: Modifying this query

Tags: sql, sql-server

This query gives me all the information that I need, however I'm wanting to display it differently if possible. The current result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Gh7c.jpg

```
DECLARE @MainHospital varchar(50)='HOSPITAL 1';
SELECT MainEmail, chkOutpatient, chkPartB
FROM SurveyPicList
WHERE MainHospital = @MainHospital
GROUP BY MainHospital, MainEmail, chkOutpatient, chkPartB
```

I'm trying to return 2 different list of MainEmail [comma-delimited](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MnzzL.jpg) if they = "on" in chkOutpatient and chkPartB. So only 2 cells of data as a result. 1 header of chkOutpatient with a list of comma dilmeted emails that = "on", and 1 header of chkPartB with the same.

So for chkPartB, something like this?https://i.stack.imgur.com/y54S2.jpg

```
SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + MainEmail AS chkPartB
FROM SurveyPicList
WHERE MainHospital = @MainHospital
AND chkPartB = 'on'
```

Please let me know if my question is unclear or if I need to give more info.

Comment: @Mihai I dont think CASE would work as OP needs to iterate through the  result set and concatenate the values..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH Outpatients AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT MainEmail
    FROM SurveyPicList
    WHERE MainHospital = @MainHospital
          AND chkOutpatient = 'on'
)
,OutpatientsRawCsv AS (
    SELECT (
       SELECT ',' + MainEmail
       FROM Outpatients
       FOR XML PATH('')
    ) AS Csv
)
,PartBs AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT MainEmail
    FROM SurveyPicList
    WHERE MainHospital = @MainHospital
          AND chkPartB = 'on'
)
,PartBRawCsv AS (
    SELECT (
       SELECT ',' + MainEmail
       FROM PartBs
       FOR XML PATH('')
    ) AS Csv
)
SELECT STUFF(OutpatientsRawCsv.Csv, 1, 1, '') AS OutpatientsCsv
      ,STUFF(PartBRawCsv.Csv, 1, 1, '') AS PartBCsv
FROM OutpatientsRawCsv
     CROSS JOIN PartBRawCsv
```

Comment: Nice answer! I was going to use recursive CTE but this is a much simpler solution...

Comment: Getting a 'invalid column name' for Csv in the `SELECT STUFF(Csv, 1, 1, '')`

Comment: Sorry for the extra '

Comment: I should of recognized it. If I simply use a `UNION` between the 2, I get a `Incorrect Syntax near WITH. Expecting '(', ALL or SELECT.`. Ideas?